# R Markdown - Table of contents is empty when rendering from script

Tags: r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

When i use the function `rmarkdown::render("./test.Rmd")` to generate my report the table of contents only has the title but nothing inside. Instead, when i use the knit button it works fine.

Is there a way to solve this issue? I have to use the render function because I need some of its params

Here is a test r markdown file just in case:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Myself"
date: "4/1/2022"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Header 1

# Header 2

## Header 2.1

### Header 2.1.1
````

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: @Franco I assume you were working in Linux when you had this problem? Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rmarkdown::render("your_rmarkdown.Rmd", word_document(toc=TRUE))
```

Other parameters you can find [there](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/word_document.html)

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. It still shows the title "Table of contents" and nothing above

Comment: @Franco By me it works. Try to update rmarkdown library.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem for me, either. Ended up filling an issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2471

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what is going on with the Rmd to docx conversion when there's a table of contents involved, but after reporting this as an issue [in rmkardown's github page](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2471) **cderv** gave me a valuable hint to solve the problem.

For them, who were working in MS word, at opening the file word asked if they wanted to update the Table of Contents. After they clicked "yes" to the question, the table magically appeared.

I'm using libreoffice, and it didn't ask anything when the file opened. I however, rightclicked the table (it has a distinct gray background) and selected the option "update index". And there the table was populated with the contents.

**Solution**

1. Open the file. If you open it in word, it may ask you if you want to "update fields that may refer to other files". Say yes and that's all.
2. If you are using libreoffice, Right-click on the table of contents and
3. Select update index.